# C++ variable extern declarations

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, constants, extern

I have declared some constants in a header file:

```
extern int  g_iShortSize1FrameEncoded=30;
extern int  g_iByteSize1FrameEncoded=(g_iShortSize1FrameEncoded*2);
extern int  g_iShortSize1FrameDecoded=960;
extern int  g_iByteSize1FrameDecoded=(g_iShortSize1FrameDecoded*2);
```

This is really convenient for me because I need to use these "constants" in various apps and change them often, and I want to do this only once so that I don't forget to change anything.

It compiles fine.

However my declaration is a bit "wild".

I have to trust the compiler will compile it in the right way.

Is my approach fine anyway?

I will not change these values at runtime, only during development.

I have 3 different applications, and all consume / need these values.

In the applications I simply wanted to include them as

```
#include "..\..\myconstants.h"
```

Comment: what about declaring with initialization and without extern keyword in the cpp source, where it is placed, and with extern keyword and without initialization in header file included from every cpp file?

Comment: Can you give an example? I don't know how that would look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you'd just put this in header file:

```
extern const int  g_iShortSize1FrameEncoded;
extern const int  g_iByteSize1FrameEncoded;
extern const int  g_iShortSize1FrameDecoded;
extern const int  g_iByteSize1FrameDecoded;
```

and this in .cpp file corresponding to that header:

```
const int  g_iShortSize1FrameEncoded=30;
const int  g_iByteSize1FrameEncoded=(g_iShortSize1FrameEncoded*2);
const int  g_iShortSize1FrameDecoded=960;
const int  g_iByteSize1FrameDecoded=(g_iShortSize1FrameDecoded*2);
```

This way linker knows that variables are placed in one compilation unit and refers to them from other compilation units. Also note the `const` keyword -- you wrote that they are constants.

Comment: That's fine if you need external linkage for some reason. Putting `const` (and not `extern`) definitions in the header, with no need for a separate source file, is easier to maintain and gives more scope for compiler optimisation.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not fine, and they are not constants. By initialising an `extern` variable in its declaration, the declaration becomes a definition. Since it has external linkage, it must obey the One Definition Rule and be defined just once; but yours will be defined wherever the header is included.

If they are constants, then make them so, with internal linkage:

```
const int  g_iShortSize1FrameEncoded=30;
^^^^^
```

On the other hand you say you need to "change them often". If you mean they actually change at runtime (rather than changing them by editing the initialiser and recompiling), then they can't be constants; instead, you'll need to declare them in the header and define them in exactly one source file:

```
// declarations in header
extern int g_iShortSize1FrameEncoded; // no initialiser

// definitions in source file
int g_iShortSize1FrameEncoded = 30;
```

In either case, the variables will be initialised in the order of their definitions; so as long as no value depends on a later variable's value, they will get the expected values.

Comment: I don't need to change them at runtime.

Comment: @tmighty: In that case, ignore the last paragraph and make them `const`.

Comment: But is the way I do it okay? I mean, I have to trust in the compiler compiling g_iShortSize1FrameEncoded first. If the compiler decides for some reason to compile g_iByteSize1FrameEncoded first, g_iShortSize1FrameEncoded will contain some unpredictable value. Or is the compiler smart enough or generally compiles from top to bottom?

Comment: @tmighty: No it's not okay, as I explain in the first paragraph. But they *are* guaranteed to be initialised in the order of the definitions.

Comment: Yes, I know... the const is missing. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your reply. I would very much like to define it in the header only. I don't have a specific source file that I could use for this. These values are needed in several places in 3 apps. I didn't want to bother with doing anything to initialize the variables. I only wanted to use them. Is there no easy way to do that?

Comment: Okay, I think I misread your reply. However, the other reply was a bit easier to understand. I have therefore accepted the other reply although it was basically the same, I think.

Comment: @tmighty: Except the other answer is telling you to keep the external linkage, and provide a separate definition in a source file; which you say you don't want. There's no need for that: as my answer says, just replace `extern` with `const` in the header to get internal linkage, and you don't need a separate definition.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of global variables is usually used like this:

some_header.h:

```
#ifndef SOME_HEADER_FILE_INCLUDED
#define SOME_HEADER_FILE_INCLUDED

extern int  g_iShortSize1FrameEncoded;
extern int  g_iByteSize1FrameEncoded;
extern int  g_iShortSize1FrameDecoded;
extern int  g_iByteSize1FrameDecoded;

#endif
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "some_header.h"

int g_iShortSize1FrameEncoded = 30;
int g_iByteSize1FrameEncoded = (g_iShortSize1FrameEncoded * 2);
int g_iShortSize1FrameDecoded = 960;
int g_iByteSize1FrameDecoded = (g_iShortSize1FrameDecoded * 2);

void another(void);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   another();
   return 0;
}
```

another.cpp:

```
#include "some_header.h"

void another(void)
{
    g_iShortSize1FrameEncoded = 50;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I don't want to initiate the variables. I was looking for a simpler solution.